# .NET and Angular Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I am creating a .NET and Angular project from scratch. I added the "ASP.NET Core Web API" template from visual studio and also used `npm run ng new ClientApp` to and my angular side to the project. I have already created my package.json file and fixed my project file to include the correct things I need to run the program but every time I go to run `npm run ng build` the program either says it can't find the package.json file (even though it tells me the exact directory of where it is. Or I go to run the project via IIS express and the site just says localhost can't be found.

I understand this isn't a lot of information so if you need any more information please ask. I'll add the code for any files as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try creating package.json file in the same folder with "npm init" command. This will create a package.json file, then you can replace the content of the file that you currently have.

Hopefully this will fix package.json not found error.

Comment: I am now receiving the error "This build requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found"

Comment: @Lwood the problem here is the missing "angular.json" file. what you can do is create a new directory and run this command into it. "ng new 'name'". This command will create a new angular app template. You can copy required files from this folder to your project. Hope this will help.

Comment: I have ran that command already however I still receive the same issue. Could it be a problem with my angular.json file?

Comment: @Lwood please make sure that you are running build command inside correct folder. Simple solution is to make a new project using ng new command and replace your src folder and package.json file with it. It should work.

Comment: The project has been built and can now be served from "npm run ng serve" but I want to use .NET to run the program from IIS. However, when I do so I get the error that the localhost port could not be found.